# deleting a line in a file using Thor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor

Is it possible using Thor actions to delete a line(s) of text from a file. For example I would like to delete ruby comments.
So far I have found 2 actions: `comment_lines` - which comments out lines, and `gsub_file`

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Does this not work to remove comments?

```
gsub_file(filename, /#.*$/, '')
```

Edit:

If you want to remove comments and delete lines with only comment information, you could try:

```
gsub_file(filename, /\S*#.*$/, '')   # removes partial comments
gsub_file(filename, /^\s*#.*\n/, '') # removes full line comments
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that but I think the negative with this is that I will now result in having empty lines where there used to be comments. Ideally I would like to have as few extraneous lines as possible.

Comment: Hmm... I thought the second one would kill the `\n` as well.

Comment: @pschuegr It does; the second one removes the line completely for me.